# Is there a function that can convert a space separated string integer ['5 2 2','4 2 3'] to yield [[5, 2, 2], [4, 2, 3]]

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string with space separated integers `['5 2 2','4 2 3']` the expected output should be a nested list with each integer string forming a list

```
[[5, 2, 2], [4, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note that this is not a free code writing service. Please show your attempts and ask a specific question.

Comment: You might want to look at [`string.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split)

Comment: You should check my answer if you want to see a solution that truly 'yields' =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` function to convert inner list to `int` along with `list comprehension`

```
x = ['5 2 2','4 2 3']

print([list(map(int, i.split())) for i in x])
```

Output:

```
[[5, 2, 2], [4, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly do that using **`list comprehension`** in python.
You can read more about **`list comprehension`** at [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Here is the code to achieve this,

```
old_list = ['5 2 2','4 2 3']
new_list = [[ int(num) for num in string.split() ] for string in old_list ]
print(new_list)
```

**The output will be,**

```
[[5, 2, 2], [4, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Clean solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use "split"

```
>>> '1 2 3'.split(' ')
[1,2,3]
```

code

```
Lnumber = ['5 2 2','4 2 3']
nat = []
for i in Lnumber:
    ret=[] # [5,2,2] and [4,2,3]
    for i in i.split(' '):ret+=[int(i)] # Convert string to int in list And put in ret
    nat+=[ret]
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you did say **yield**, so:

```
>>> li = ['1 2 3', '4 5 6']
>>>
>>> def yield_nums(num_str):
...     for ns in num_str.split():
...         yield int(ns)
...         
>>> def yield_nested(num_str_list):
...     for ns in num_str_list:
...         yield list(yield_nums(ns))
...         
>>> list(yield_nested(li))
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>>
```

=)

Comment: The OP did not definitely mean that "yield" :D

Comment: It was worth a shot

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ['1 2 3', '4 5 6']    
b = [i.split(' ') for i in a]
print (b)
```